# Foundation 4 Forms JavaScript: disable the custom <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I am trying to use Foundation's forms JavaScript to use their custom radio and checkbox elements, but I don't want to use Foundation for custom selects. I know that I can use the `.no-custom` class to prevent Foundation from applying custom elements, but I want to do it on a global scale.

According to the documentation here: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html I should be able to do this by passing in parameters to the `forms` library. So I'm attempting this:

```
$(document).foundation('forms', {
    settings: { disable_class: 'no-custom, select'}
});
```

But it doesn't seem to work.  I'm able to do it by altering the actual forms library code like this:

```
settings: {
  disable_class: 'no-custom, select', // before edit was: disable_class: 'no-custom',
  ...
},
```

But I'd rather not edit the library. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for digging up this old topic but the given solution does only remove the custom css, the event handlers of the element are still attached, so you have to add this to your element: `data-customforms="disabled"` to disable any event handlers which the Zurb Foundation will add to your element automatically.

In example

```
<form class="custom">
    <select class="custom">
        <option>This one is a custom select element</option>
    </select>
    <select class="no-custom" data-customforms="disabled">
        <option>This one is not a custom select element</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

js

```
$(document).foundation('forms', {disable_class: 'no-custom'});
```

html

```
<select class="no-custom"></select>
```